# how could i change the input placehoder in dialogflow messenger?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I need to change the placeholder text of the dialogflow messenger chatbot for customer requirements

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
<df-messenger
  intent="WELCOME"
  chat-title="gestion de citas"
  agent-id="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  language-code="es"
></df-messenger>
```

[image]

We have review deeply HTML customizations
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#html-customize

and CSS customizations
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#css-customize

from google cloud guides

How would it be possible to change the placeholder text?

Comment: Can you please share the tools you are using to render your web-page?.

The placeholder text can be changed using a command like:

document.querySelector("body > df-messenger").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > df-messenger-chat").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > df-messenger-user-input").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div.input-box-wrapper > input[type=text]").placeholder = "THE-TEXT-YOU-WANT-TO-ADD”

Is it possible for you to embed javascript code like the above one in a script, or in a HTML’s <script> tag?.

Comment: I recommend going through this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65215694/dialogflow-messenger-height-customization-issue-on-firefox-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation you’ve provided, there isn’t any built-in functionality to change the placeholder text.

However, you can create code to customize the placeholder using javascript or jQuery.

Here’s a sample code I tested with:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){ document.querySelector("df-messenger").shadowRoot.querySelector("df-messenger-chat").shadowRoot.querySelector("df-messenger-user-input").shadowRoot.querySelector(".input-box-wrapper > input").placeholder="New placeholder text” }, 1000);
</script>
```

I got the placeholder element by looking into the Browser Developer tools.

Here's the sample output:

[image]