# Dialogflow messenger height customization issue on Firefox browser

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, dialogflow-es

I've developed a chatbot messenger using the dialogflow-ES. When I integrate it with my Wordpress website, as you can see in the attached snapshop, the height of the chat window overlaps across the site's navigation bar.

[Customize the height of the chat widget of Dialogflow messenger integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63394248/customize-the-height-of-the-chat-widget-of-dialogflow-messenger-integration)

By going through this first answer in the the link above, I changed my code and could successfully achieve the customization required for my chatbot. But the problem I'm having now is the code **only works on Google chrome and Edge** browsers and it **doesn't work on Firefox**. As I went through the browser compatibility documentations, I found out that "adpotedStyleSheets" functionality doesn't work on firefox.

[On Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYC4S.png)   [On Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFeR3.png)

This is the test server link. You can check the difference using it.
http://3.137.86.206/testingbot.html

**Is there any optional way to implement this, as it works in both Chrome and Firefox browsers??**

Here's my code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    window.addEventListener('dfMessengerLoaded', function (event) {
        $r1 = document.querySelector("df-messenger");
        $r2 = $r1.shadowRoot.querySelector("df-messenger-chat");
        $r5 = $r2.shadowRoot.querySelector("df-message-list");

        var sheet = new CSSStyleSheet;
        sheet.replaceSync(`div.chat-wrapper[opened="true"] { height: 420px; width: 300px; }`); //To change Height and Width
        $r2.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [ sheet ];

        var sheet3 = new CSSStyleSheet;
        sheet3.replaceSync(`#messageList .message {font-size:0.9em !important;}
         #messageList .message.bot-message {margin-right: 20px ;} 
         #messageList .message.user-message {margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 6px;} 
         .message-list-wrapper.minimized #messageList {margin-right: -15px;} 
         .message-list-wrapper.minimized #dismissIcon {padding: 1px}`); //To change margin sizes of user and bot messages
        $r5.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [ sheet3 ];

        var sheet5 = new CSSStyleSheet;
        sheet5.replaceSync(`button#widgetIcon .df-chat-icon {height: 56px; width: 56px; left: 0px; top:0px;}`); //To change chat icon 
        $r1.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [ sheet5 ];    
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing a lot of research to try to solve this problem and I found a way to customize it for all browsers.
The styleSheet constructor is currently only supported by Google Chrome.

I recommend this method to create CSS customizations in the chatbot components for cross browser.

```
const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger');
dfMessenger.addEventListener('df-messenger-loaded', function () {
        $r1 = document.querySelector("df-messenger");
        $r2 = $r1.shadowRoot.querySelector("df-messenger-chat");

        var style = document.createElement( 'style' );
        style.innerHTML = 'div.chat-wrapper[opened="true"]{height:480px;max-height:480px;}';
        $r2.shadowRoot.appendChild( style );
});
```